# url path issue after deployment on apache tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, war

i have deployed a website on apache Tomcat server 8.0 *(lets suppose the folder name is WebsiteFolderName)* in the form of war file. when i access the website by url **[www.example.com]** , my site redirects to **[www.example.com/login.jsp]** and then gives me a invalid path error.

But when i access the site using **[www.example.com/WebsiteFolderName]** , my site redirects to **[www.example.com/WebsiteFolderName/login.jsp]** and then login page works fine but rest of my website pages also face this path issue.

what should i do so that i can access my website using [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) instead of http://www.example.com/WebsiteFolderName

Comment: So are you using an apache webserver for accessing the app? Otherwise please remove the `apache` tag.

Comment: Hey, if you just want a fast solution then rename your war file to ROOT.war. This will remove the `WebsiteFolderName`from the path

Comment: Do you use any kind of framework for you application?

Comment: Go to Project Properties and check Your Deployment Assembly where it content the directory of your jsp file or not.

Answer (score 0):

You got two easy options:

1. Do not change your war file name and configure conf/server.xml with details about your war file.

```
<Context path="" docBase="your_war_file" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

2. Rename your war file to ROOT.war

Option 2 is easier, but option 1 is easier for fast deployment.

Comment: This may or may not be your problem. I missread OP question, I did not notice that www.example.com actually worked.